# NXT 2.1 And Windows 10 V2004

Tags: nxt, nxt-g

Has anyone had any luck installing the NXT 2.1 software onto a Windows 10 PC running V2004 19041.1052 build? I keep getting an error:

> This publisher has been blocked from running software on your PC.

I realize NXT is no longer supported and is not guaranteed to work on Windows 10 but trying to understand if this is still possible.

This error does not occur on Windows 10 V1809 and allows me to install without issues.

Comment: Could you update your question with error message you get please? By either pasting exact text or just simply attaching a picture.

Comment: <https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-fix-this-publisher-has-been-blocked-from-running-software> claims to have a solution to this exact error, now that we can see the message you got.